# Interpreting unknown symbol on MapBox GL JS map

Tags: symbology, legend, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In my MapBox GL JS map, I've encountered this weird, thick line that goes all over the place:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't seem to be a railroad, or a road of any kind. Possibly some kind of border marker. But I cannot find any "legend" that explains it. I assume it's a standard symbol.

Can you tell me what it means?

Comment: Although a dash-dot line is often used as a border, it really could be anything. Only the author of the map could tell. Can we inspect this map somewhere by ourselves?

Comment: @Berend Not easily. It's an application on my computer, and MapBox doesn't let anyone use the web version of any map without an API key. At least that's my experience.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why does that bot post that in every question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected [one of the examples](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA#14.87/51.2237/5.57424) on the mapbox site, and a similar symbol is used for province borders. The solid line is a national border.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]